# Itemize - page break only after items

Tags: page-breaking, itemize

I'm trying to solve a problem. One solution might be to prevent a page break in an itemized list on an individual item. So, if I would have several items a page break can only occur after an item is finished.

I didn't find a solution how prevent it. Using `samepage` environment caused that no page break occurs after `\item`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Its simple command (marked below)

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \interlinepenalty10000     % crucial change!!!
    \item First unbreakable item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

:-)

Comment: Could you please add a code?

Comment: This didn't prevent a page break in the middle of an item when I added it to my enumerate environment.